# Where can one download "official" mono appliances?

Tags: mono, virtual-machine

I used to rely on the [Novell ftp site](http://ftp.novell.com/pub/mono/appliance/) to retrieve fully fledged Linux based Mono virtual machines.

Latest VM available is Mono-2.10.2, published on April, 26th 2011 (few days before the ["Attachmate" incident](http://www.internetnews.com/skerner/2011/05/attachmate-lays-off-mono-emplo.html)).

The [VMWare_Image](http://www.mono-project.com/VMware_Image) page, on the Mono project site, states that *"You can download the VMware image with Mono pre-installed and pre-configured from our Downloads page."*. Unfortunately, I can't find anything relevant on the [Downloads](http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html) page.

Now that [Xamarin has came to an agreement with Novell](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2011/Jul-18.html), is there a new source where one could download preconfigured Mono appliances?

Comment: That's a question to ask on the http://www.mono-project.com/Mailing_Lists , probably mono-list or mono-devel-list.

Answer (score 1):

I know what you mean, there used to be official images to grab from the mono-project.com page. The images were build using open(suse) build service and based on opensuse. The official builds are outdated, but you can try searching the SUSE Gallery, which is basically a public collection of user-build opensuse images, using different software selection.

A search for mono: http://susestudio.com/search?q=mono

I have not tested any of these myself, but you might want to look these in particular:
http://susestudio.com/a/LZOHnh/rudis-mono-appliance
http://susestudio.com/a/O6ALub/opensuse-114-gnome3-with-monodevelop

Depending on your need, you could also create your own spin of openSUSE, adding the xamarin rpm repo in the webclient and have SUSE studio built it for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I'm after a source of official pre-packaged virtual machines for each major and minor Mono releases. This is quite useful when you're willing to assess the compatibility of something against a Mono version.

Comment: There used to be the official images offered by novell on the OBS, which were then linked on the mono-project.com website. However, since the Attachmate incident and the seperation of mono into xamarin, those images we left unmaintained. AFAIK no one at xamarin is maintaining prepacked mono vmware images, since the software they sell is not supported on linux. They only sell Monotouch/Mono4Android to Mac OS X and Windows platform, so I wouldn't count on "official" prepackaged mono linux images in the future. You might only find community packed ones.

Comment: The current state of the Mono website is a complete mess, they should update their pages to reflect what @dyna said.